# How can I refresh my FormView after an edit?

Tags: asp.net, formview

I am using a `FormView` to select companies from a database. This `FormView` is bound to an `ObjectDataSource`, which is bound to a `DropDownList`. When a user selects a company from the `DropDownList`, the `FormView` is populated with information pertaining to the company (`AutoPostBack` is enabled on the `DropDownList` to provide dynamic record changing). My `FormView` supports insert, update, and delete functions, of which all three work.

My problem is as follows: After I edit a record in the `FormView`, the record successfully changes, however, it is completely removed from the screen. Only after I select a new company from my `DropDownList` will a record re-display in the `FormView`.

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to databind again.

```
void FormView_ItemInserted(Object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
  Gridview.Databind();
}
```

Comment: +1.  Same approach as me, tapping into a different event.  If you go to this approach, you also have to handle the Updated and Deleted events, but it works.

Comment: Your right - OP needs to handle update and delete as well. Also it would be advisable to perform a check to confirm that the insert/update/delete has been succesful

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the child control to be databound when the parent control has been modified.

I've found that the most reliable palce to do this is in the parent control's DataBound event. After a successful edit, this event is called, because the control needs to re-bind to the edited data.

Here's a snippet from some actual code of mine where I do something similar.  In it, I have a control called QuestionGroupResutls that has child records in a control called QuestionResults.

```
void QuestionGroupResults_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QuestionGroupsEditingDetailsView1.DataBind();
    QuestionResults.DataBind();

}
```

I have this in Page_Load, but you can specify this declaratively in the asmx (I just don't have a code sample).

```
 QuestionGroupResults.DataBound += new EventHandler(QuestionGroupResults_DataBound);
```

I don't know the name of your controls, but you should be able to do the same thing with yours.